# grouping on two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't come up with proper query for this.

If any `ID` in `GroupName` group in `#target` matches `ID` in `#source`, its whole group should take its `#source GroupName`.

For example,  `A` in `#target` has `GroupName = 'beta'`, and `ID=A` exists in `#source`, everything in `#target` where `GroupName = 'beta'` should be updated to `'alpha'` from `#source`.

```
create table #Source
(
ID varchar(55) UNIQUE,
GroupName varchar(55))

create table #Target
(
ID varchar(55) UNIQUE,
GroupName varchar(55))

insert #Source
select 'A','alpha'
union
select 'B','alpha'
union
select 'C','alpha'

insert #Target
select 'A','beta'
union
select 'B','beta'
union
select 'C','teta'
union
select 'D','teta'
union
select 'E','zeta'
union
select 'F','zeta'

select * from #Source
select * from #Target
```

So, #target should be updated to this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that out

```
update trg
set GroupName = e.srcGroup
from
(
select distinct t.GroupName,s.GroupName as srcGroup 
from #Target t
inner join #Source s on t.ID = s.ID
) e
inner join #Target trg on trg.GroupName = e.GroupName
```